# biblatex - how to add backref list with APA style?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, apa-style, back-referencing

Regarding the `backref` option, the biblatex manual says:

> Strictly speaking, this option only controls whether the biblatex package collects the data required to print such references. This feature still has to be supported by the selected bibliography style. All standard styles which ship with this package do so.

How to implement/invoke the feature in a "nonstandard" package?

**MNWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english, american]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=apa,
            backref=true %% or so I thought??
           ]
          {biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@book{sloterdijk2013change,
  title={You Must Change Your Life},
  author={Sloterdijk, P.},
  publisher={Polity Press},
  year={2013}
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{references.bib}

\begin{document}
\noindent Cf. Sloterdijk \citeyear[(pp. 84--85)]{sloterdijk2013change}. 

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: I don't see a backref]

Comment: As a first guess, I assume you have to look at what a standard style does in its BibliographyDrivers and adapt/add that to the drivers for APA.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I might be a little late, but as this is the number one search result in Google for "biblatex apa backref" it might be of help for others:

There is a dedicated option in biblatex-apa for this:

```latex
\usepackage[style=apa,apabackref=true]{biblatex}
```

Explanation for this special handling from the [package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-apa/biblatex-apa.pdf):

> It is not APA style to include backreferences in the References to pages where citations of the entry occur. However, this is very useful, especially in proofing and so if you set the apabackref option to ‘true’, these are enabled. The default is ‘false’.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

Indeed, per @jon, adding things like this to `biblatex.cfg` works for me:

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
  \setunit{\bibpagespunct}%
  \printfield{pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{addendum}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{related}%
  \usebibmacro{apa:finpunct}%
  \usebibmacro{apa:pageref}%
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%%%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
```